# Referring Since *uncertain but at least years ago* time in the past

Tags: word-choice

> Sentence A : Since that time back then  i always study hard

Question : please correct Sentence A, just like a native english speaker would use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'd phrase it something like this:

> I always study hard, and I have for years now.

The second half of the sentence gives an indeterminate lower bound that is at least "years" ago.

Comment: That works, but changing as little as possible, I'd probably arrive at: *Since then, I always study hard,* or *Since then, I've always studied hard* I think it's the redundancy of *since that time* and *back then* that's the biggest issue here.